# Random click to div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, random, click

I have 2 divs with 2 different class:

1. div class name is: good
2. div class name is: bad

I would like to click with javascript (user script) randomly for this divs. I never coded in javascript i just found this code in internet.

I have this code:

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() {
setInterval(function(){
$('div.good').click();
$('div.bad').click();
}, 5000);

}
addJQuery(main);
```

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: I would like the following:
Click to this 2 different divs with randomly

Comment: You are doing nothing when the div is clicked!!!

Comment: Click Once to the <div class="bad"></div> and once to the <div class="good"></div>

This is like classification. If i click to this 2 div after 30 sec i have other case and i will see again the good or bad button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like what you are looking to do is perform an action with one of these two divs. It doesn't really make sense to fake a click, because all that does is run code, which could just as easily be executed in another, far more convenient manner. What do you want to happen when the div is clicked?

Comment: It is a classification website. First i have to wait 30 sec and after i will have 2 buttons like "good" and "bad". If i click for one i will have other classification and I can vote again. I dont want to check every page just make a random clicks.

Answer (score 0):

First, 2 questions:

1. What are you trying to accomplish? The task you present is rather strange and I can't think of any applications that can't be done another way.
2. Is there a reason you are appending jQuery asynchronously?

Nevertheless, the following code will dispatch click events to one of two divs, chosen randomly, 30 seconds after page load.

```
function main() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5)
            $('div.good').click();
        else
            $('div.bad').click();
    }, 30*1000);
}
```

A more generic solution would be to write a random choice function, which chooses randomly from a set of N items.

```
Math.randomChoice = function(collection) {
    return collection[Math.floor(Math.random() * collection.length)];
};

function main() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var elem = Math.randomChoice(['good', 'bad']);
        $('div.' + elem).click();
    }, 30*1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks the first one is enough for me. I never used scripts I just heard i have to use jQuery.

Comment: After reading your comment on the other answer, I realized I forgot the setInterval. Don't forget to put the main() function in a timeout if you want to wait 30 sec.

Comment: Sorry but im 100% illiterate in javascript, can you write it down?

Comment: Edited above. By the way, `setInterval()` causes the code to run in intervals, while `setTimeout()` causes it to execute once after the specified number of millis. Not sure which one you want.